# flickr post picture 400 bad request

Tags: node.js, oauth, flickr, image-uploading

[gist of nodejs application](https://gist.github.com/4124038)

I'm trying to upload picture to flickr using [api](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html). It returns **400 bad request**. I've created test upload server. It returns:

```
{ photo: 
  { size: 30792,
    path: '/tmp/f877969414d950e1089bd1c75f8e5bcf.jpg',
    name: 'picture.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    ...
}
{ title: 'test photo' }
```

Request and picture **are valid**. What street magic should I use to fix flickr's server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flickr's upload does not support oauth according to specification. Workarounds are situated in flickraw ruby library